# CSS sprite icon in form input - How to change alignment?

Tags: css

I can create a text input including a beautiful icon in it ( when I have just one icon) :

CSS:

```
.phoneIcon {
    background-image: url('../icons/phone.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    padding-right: 45px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="w3-padding-16">
    <input type="text" class="phoneIcon w3-input" />
  </div>
```

Result is successful:
[image]

Now the the problem is when having many icons and want to use CSS sprite.

CSS:

```
.phoneIcon {
    background-image: url('../icons/map118.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
    background-position: -0px -122px;    
    padding-right: 45px;    
}
```

HTML : same as above.

Result : unsuccessful:
[image]

I do not know how to move my new icon to right  side. In sprite mode, I have `background-position: -0px -122px;` and I can't use  `background-position: right center;` at the same time. In the other way, the default position of background in CSS is top-left , and I need to use the position attribute to specify the position of my icon (in px)  and can not  use it to edit the place of selected-icon in input box. I tried `float:right` but :(  .I tried to use both `background-position: -0px -122px;` and `background-position: right center;` , the result was foolish, because it loads another icon instead of my desire icon.(In fact it always loads "center right" position of sprite image).

I just need to move the icon to right side.
I don't know how to make it to load position of "0px -122px" and show it on right side of input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you using the same class for several icons?
I made a solution for one icon in one input field like this.

```
.w3-padding-16 img {
  position: absolute;
}

.w3-padding-16 {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  /* adjust these as you see fit
  If you increase one, you'll have to increae
  the other as well.
  */
  width: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```
<div class="w3-padding-16">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/100/000000/phone.png" width="100%"/>
    <input class="input-field" type="text" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/battleaxe/voj1a8ry/9/